# get current script id

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 and  have a script which i to run on multiple views.

When load the script i want to know in which view was loaded?

example: If i open page one the script will load test.js with the id="one" `<script src"test.js" id="one">`

If load page two: `<script src="test.js" id="two">` the same script with another id="two".

How can i get the current script id? In test.js i want to know which view(page) was calling test.js script to run (page one or page two) I have a custom function for each page). Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest adding the determining id or class to the `body` element. Then you can do something like `if (document.body.id === 'one') { ... }`...

Comment: yup......did the trick....thx a lot :)